# Python: why is "if <some integer>" equivalent to "if True"?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have come across this piece of code:

```
counts = 128 * [0]

# some other steps here that modify the variable counts...
# in the end we have something like counts=[12, 583, 0, etc. , etc., 384]

for i in range(len(counts)):
    if counts[i]:
        outfile.write("%-12s%d\n" % (display(i), counts[i]))
```

Regarding the `if` statement, I understand that it is introduced so that it skips the instruction when `counts[i]==0`. That's because `0` is equivalent to `False`. But on the other side, I thought that any other integer (apart from 1) was not equivalent to `True`. In fact, if I type `3 == True` on the shell, I get `False` as an answer. So, is there any particular reason why `if <some integer>` is equivalent to `if True`?

Comment: ...because all nonzero integers are truthy in Python? Try `bool(3)`; you'll see that when coerced to a boolean, 3 *becomes* `True`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`3 == True` is comparing 3-as-an-integer to True-as-a-boolean.

`if 3:` is coercing 3 to a boolean.

You'll see that `bool(3) == True` is true.

Answer (score 3):

[Quoting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - **zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j.`**
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the
>     integer zero or bool value False.
>
> **All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.**

Answer (score 0):

Simple in your shell try `bool(3)`(which is `True`) and `bool(0)`(which is `False`).

`bool` of zero is `False` and `bool` of non-zero is `True`.